# Creating Azure iot-hub and device on it using node.js code

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am creating java script website to create to the Azure iot-hub and create device on azure iot-hub. Is there any way to do this using node.js code. Like creation of azure-iot-hub and device should be hidden to the user of the website.

Azure iot-hub should be created using code rather than creating manually by signing into azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The management API for IoTHub is all RESTful, so you can use Javascript library like fetch to manage resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iot-hub-resource/create-or-update